# How to pass data to widgets from template to index.js in apostrophe?

Tags: apostrophe-cms, apostrophe

If I pass options to a widget like in this code
`{{ apos.singleton(data.widget, 'column'+loop.index, 'eventi-categorie',optionPage) }}`

How can i get optionPage values in the module code in index.js file (I really mean in the constructor or in self.load ) to query needed pieces?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since templates are synchronous, widgets are always loaded before the template is rendered. As a result you cannot access the `options` passed at template level in the `load` method of your widgets module.

What I recommend you do as an alternative is use either (a) settings in the schema of the widget, which are available in the load method, or (b) separate subclasses of your module, which can have different load methods to load content differently.

If these solutions won't work for your use case please provide more details.

I also note that you are using a loop index in an area name. This is usually not the best way to get that effect. Instead, use either a field of type `array` with an area in its own schema, or an area made up of widgets that have an area in their own schema. The latter is particularly intuitive for editors. You can pass the `blockLevelControls: true` option to the outer area to make it a little easier for editors to distinguish the controls for the outer area from those for the inner areas.

Comment: Thanks you but I'm a little bit confused. Can you share some documentation about you're suggesting with me?

Comment: Custom widgets, including how to add schema fields to them, so the user can make choices when editing them that *are* visible to the load method: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/core-concepts/editable-content-on-pages/custom-widgets.html

And nested widgets, as an alternative to loop indexes in area names: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/core-concepts/editable-content-on-pages/layout-widgets.html